# CSS Fluid-Fixed layout with equal height columns

Tags: css, layout

I am new to CSS, so please forgive me if this is a real stupid question! 
But the thing is, I have been trying this for last 48 hours but still unable to get it right. All I want is a CSS layout for this:

1. Two columns, left fluid, right fixed (300px)
2. Both columns are same height, right column has a background color throughout.
3. A 100px height header.
4. A 300px height footer.
5. Whole thing encapsulated in a center position container.
   This container has a max-width of 960px and min-width of 480px. Whenever screen is less than 480px, the fixed right column should come vertically below the left content column.
6. should Work in IE 7+, Chrome, Safari, FF.
7. No JavaScript (can't understand why this would ever be required for this)

I have tried (and still trying) to do it, but somehow can not create the same height column. I tried a few online CSS generator without luck. Any help, pointer, etc. will be greatly appreciated.

## EDIT:

Here is a jsfiddle : 'http://jsfiddle.net/GKEmA/' of what I did

Comment: please show us what you did using jsfiddle. so we can help you with your own code.

Comment: here is what I have:http://jsfiddle.net/GKEmA/

Comment: Good to see that somebody has voted my question down where all I asked was some help or pointer to help me out on a technical domain I am learning for last 2 days. This definitely got me encouraged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matthew James Taylor's [Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) article should provide a framework for solving this problem. He has solutions for both fluid and fixed columns; I believe they can be combined.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a go with using CSS table layout — no not HTML table markup, just the CSS properties. Floats aren't really designed for layout.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-CSS21-20020802/tables.html#q2

http://maketea.co.uk/2012/09/05/floats-are-dead-long-live-table-layouts.html